# Try catch with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, try-catch

I am not sure whether try/catch is performance hit or not I want to use it in one of my AngularJs application. Will you please navigate me to right direction.

Comment: try catch does not have a performance hit, it is a mechanism for catching errors.

Comment: try { someFunction() } catch(error){ console.log(error); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to handle try/catch better or handle exception and keep the log of them write a decorate around angularjs exception handler

[example here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/21/better-error-handling-in-angularjs.aspx)

```
app.config(function($provide){

    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate, $injector){
        return function(exception, cause){
            var $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
            $rootScope.addError({message:"Exception", reason:exception});
            $delegate(exception, cause);
        };
    });

});
```

Comment: It's just add it's to an error array, what to do with array is your decision